# Adding 7 days weather forecast to QGIS project

Tags: qgis, web-service, weather

The [Qweather Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QWeather/) with Yahoo Weather API gives me the real time weather info I want but I also want to add seven days weather forecast to my QGIS project. How can I implement this?

Comment: there is https://openweathermap.org which offers a free API key also for a 7 days forecast. But you need to do some programming.

Comment: Yes I saw that one but with my zero programming knowledge I had no idea how to get it to work.